# Configure Spring Web Flow with Java configuration

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

I am using Spring 3.1 and want to include Spring Web Flow 2.3. One thing I really like about Spring is that you can leave off the XML configuration in favour of Java-only configuration using `@Configuration` and `@Bean` annotations.

However, I have not yet found out how to configure Web Flow this way. The docs that turned up on my Google searches all referred to XML configuration only. Is it possible, does anyone have any pointers?

EDIT:
I was not asking about the flow definition, but rather for a replacement for the `webflow-config` schema. At the moment, configuration items such as `flow-registry` and `flow-executor` have to go in Spring-XML files, along with the flow handler mapping referring to them.

Comment: did you find an answer to your question? ie. configuration for webflow and not flow-definitions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the flow definitions, then no. Java base configuration for Webflow was to be part of Webflow 3. The most recent status update can be found in [this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?86858-Discuss-Spring-Web-Flow-3-Development/page3).

> There is currently no set date for a Spring Web Flow 3 release. Version 3 tickets are currently being reviewed for inclusion in 2.4 or subsequent releases so once again if there are things you care about please vote, comment, and discuss. The flagship Web Flow 3 item -- Java-based flow definitions, is still under consideration although currently on hold as we move forward with other important goals mentioned above.

Comment: javaconfig is now available - http://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/system-setup.html