# How to redirect from @Controller to a flow

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-webflow

I need to redirect to a flow from a `@Controller`, but am not sure how to go about this. I need to either continue with MVC under a certain condition, or go into my flow under another condition. Here's the final line of my `/auth` method:

```
return new ModelAndView(isFlowProtected(getClientId(sessionDataPayloadJSON)) ?
    "redirect:/login-flow" :
    LoginConstants.LOGIN);
```

Essentially, I have two login flows, one through normal Spring MVC, one under webflow. Here's how I configured my flow:

```
@Bean
public FlowDefinitionRegistry flowRegistry() {
    return getFlowDefinitionRegistryBuilder().addFlowLocation("/webflow/login-flow.xml","login-flow"
            .setFlowBuilderServices(this.flowBuilderServices())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowExecutor flowExecutor() {
    return getFlowExecutorBuilder(this.flowRegistry())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public FlowBuilderServices flowBuilderServices() {
    return getFlowBuilderServicesBuilder()
            .setViewFactoryCreator(this.mvcViewFactoryCreator()) // Important!
            .setValidator(this.localValidatorFactoryBean).build();
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerMapping flowHandlerMapping() {
    FlowHandlerMapping handlerMapping = new FlowHandlerMapping();
    handlerMapping.setOrder(-1);
    handlerMapping.setFlowRegistry(this.flowRegistry());
    return handlerMapping;
}

@Bean
public FlowHandlerAdapter flowHandlerAdapter() {
    FlowHandlerAdapter handlerAdapter = new FlowHandlerAdapter();
    handlerAdapter.setFlowExecutor(this.flowExecutor());
    handlerAdapter.setSaveOutputToFlashScopeOnRedirect(true);
    return handlerAdapter;
}

@Bean
public ViewFactoryCreator mvcViewFactoryCreator() {
    MvcViewFactoryCreator factoryCreator = new MvcViewFactoryCreator();
    factoryCreator.setUseSpringBeanBinding(true);
    return factoryCreator;
}
```

Assuming my path to my flow is correct, what am I doing wrong here? How can I redirect to the `login-flow` from my `/auth` endpoint when needed? I'm getting the following error currently:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource [/webflow/login-flow.xml]
```

So maybe my path is wrong? The flow is inside of `resources/webflow`, so I think it's right, but maybe not?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a `/webflow/login-flow.xml` file in your WAR root directory? I *think* that's what that error indicates, that it can't find that file. I believe your redirect is working correctly, and your WebFlow configuration expects to find a flow configuration file at the location you specified, but it isn't finding it there.

I haven't used [Java-based WebFlow configuration before](https://docs.spring.io/spring-webflow/docs/current/reference/html/system-setup.html#basic-setup-flow-registry), so I could be misunderstanding this, but best I read this, I think you might still need Flow xml files even when you do the rest of the configuration in Java.

See [Configure Spring Web Flow with Java configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671063/configure-spring-web-flow-with-java-configuration)

Comment: I do have that `login-flow.xml` inside the `webflow` directory, which is why I'm so confused as well. It's giving me the path I expect to see, but for some reason doesn't seem to be able to find it.

Comment: `webflow` directory under where? You earlier said `resources/webflow`. What's the full path of the file, starting from the root of the war?